# How to write variable and array on the same line for a text file?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have an array called 'thelist' and it holds some numbers which I want to output to a file on the same line delimited with commas. I did this using:

```
thelist = [1,6,5,2,7]

thefile = open('test.txt', 'w')

name = "bob"

for item in thelist:
  thefile.write("%s,"%(item))
```

output:

```
1,6,5,2,7,
```

However, I want to be able to write the name and the array on the same line. So it'd look something similar to `bob 1,6,5,2,7`

I tried to use `thefile.write("%s %s,"%(name,item))` but that unfortunately does not work. I tried to search for an answer but I didn't find a solution. Any ideas? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

precede the for-loop by
`thefile.write("%s ", name)`

Your lat lines would look like this:

```
thefile.write("%s " % name)
for item in thelist:
  thefile.write("%s,"% item)
```

In addition, to remove the annoying comma at the end, you can consider

```
outStr = ",".join(map(str, thelist))
thefile.write("%s %s" %(name, outStr))
```

Comment: Your solution gave me a `TypeError: write() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (3 given)`  error which I managed to fix by doing `thefile.write("%s " %name)` and `thefile.write("%s,"% item)`. This gave me `bob 1,6,5,2,7` which also removed the comma at the end without me adding the extra code.

Answer (score 0):

```
thefile.write("{n} {l}".format(n=name, l=",".join(str(i) for i in theList)))
```